# How can I complete this proof of a algebraic topology theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The theorem is:
Let be f, g : X→Y two continuous maps between topogolical spaces and

H : X$\times$[0, 1] a homotopy such that H(x,0)=f(x) and H(x,1)=g(x).

Given $x_0\in X$ let be $y_0=f(x_0)$, $y_1=g(x_0)$ and $\tau(t)=H(x_0,t)$ a path in Y from $y_0$ and $y_1$.

Then, $g_*=\varphi_{[\tau]}\circ f_*$

i.e. $\require{AMScd}$
     \begin{CD}
    \pi_1(X,x_0) @>f_*>> \pi_1(Y,y_0)\\
    @V  V V @VV \varphi_{[\tau]} V\\
    @>>g_*> \pi_1(Y,y_1)
    \end{CD}

where

$f_*:\pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y,y_0),\space f_*([\gamma])=[f\circ \gamma]$,

$g_*:\pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y,y_1),\space g_*([\gamma])=[g\circ \gamma]$ and

$\varphi_{[\tau]}:\pi_1(Y,y_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y,y_1),\space\varphi_{[\tau]}([\gamma])=[\tau^{-1}]·[\gamma]·[\tau]$ 
In the diagram it's supposed that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ goes directly to $\pi_1(Y,y_1)$ by $g_*$

$f_*$ and $g_*$ are group homomorphism and $\varphi_{[\tau]}$ is a group isomorphism.

I began supposing

$g_*([\gamma])=\varphi_{[\tau]}\circ f_*([\gamma])=[\tau^{-1}]·[f\circ\gamma]·[\tau] \iff [\tau]·g_*([\gamma])·[\tau^{-1}]·f_*([\gamma]^{-1})=e_{y_0}$

and from here I don't know how to continue, I think there's something with four components which can help me to complete the proof.

Thanks.